# Meaning of the barotropic index

Tags: fluid-dynamics, cosmology

As far as I have understood, barotropic fluids are those that satisfy

$$p = w\rho$$

where $w$ is the so-called *barotropic index*, which ranges from $w_{min} = -1$ to $w_{max} = +1$. What is the physical meaning of this parameter in any general fluid? What would be its physical meaning if such fluid were the Universe?

Comment: I mean, you wrote down the physical meaning already; it's just the ratio of pressure to density. Is there something else you wanted to know? Like, examples or something?

Comment: Well, yes, for instance, how would behave a fluid with $\omega = 1$ or $\omega = -1$? What does $\omega = 0$ mean? And yes, maybe some examples might help, thank you.

Comment: Strictly speaking a barotropic fluid is a fluid for which pressure if a function of density only $P=P(\rho)$. In cosmology you often make the assumption $P(\rho)=w\rho$ (I've set $c=1$) in order to get simple solutions of Friedmann equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking a barotropic fluid is a fluid for which pressure is a function of density only: $P=P(\rho)$. The simplest function you can think is $P(\rho)=wc^2\rho$: this is very useful in Cosmology to describe the state equation of the "cosmic fluid" and hence get simple solutions of Friedmann equations.

For common fluids you can define the speed of sound in that fluid as $c^2_s=\frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}$, so

$$w=\frac{c_s^2}{c^2}$$

In Cosmology $P(\rho)=wc^2\rho$ is a model for the state equation of the cosmic fluid; solving Friedmann equations you get $\rho \propto a^{-3(1+w)}$ where $a$ is the scale factor. So if you have:

$w=0 \rightarrow \rho \propto a^{-3}$ you are describing a universe of non relativistic matter, since density scales with the inverse volume;

$w=1/3 \rightarrow \rho \propto a^{-4}$ you are describing a universe of radiation, since its energy scales as $a^{-1}$ (inverse of wavelength) and its energy density as $a^{-1}a^{-3}$;

$w=-1 \rightarrow \rho \propto a^{0}$ you are describing a universe of dark energy, since its energy density is constant during its evolution.